# Error reporting in C++ programming in VS code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have no problem compiling files with G++, but VS code reports an error to the C++ 11 standard syntax. I want to know how to make VS code detect the syntax normally.

> - a space is required between consecutive right angle brackets (use '> >')
> - non-aggregate type 'vector<vector >' cannot be initialized with an initializer list

Comment: Looks like you have not correctly configured VS Code to compile with C++11.  Those errors only appear in C++08 or C++03.

Comment: If these are red squiggly lines that are giving you these errors, check for a setting for intellisense where you can select what language standard it uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `"C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++11"` to settings.json. (F1 -> `Open Settings (JSON)` or `Open Workspace Settings (JSON)`)